# What happens when you call malloc on an existing variable?

Tags: c, memory-management

If a variable was already `malloc`'ed in the past, what happens if you call `malloc` on it again rather than `realloc`? Will it cause a memory leak?

I'd like to know so that I can add checks before `malloc` calls on parameters passed to functions in order to avoid potential leaks.

```
void memtest(char **foo)
{
        if ( foo )
                *foo = malloc(10); // Assuming *foo was already allocated in the past.
}
```

Should I always do the following?

```
void memtest(char **foo)
{
        if ( foo ) {
                if ( *foo ) {
                        free(*foo);

                        *foo = NULL;
                }

                *foo = malloc(10);
        }
}
```

Comment: Question would be better if you will add a code snippet.

Comment: There is no such thing as "calling malloc on a variable".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing as "calling `malloc` on a variable".

`malloc` finds some "free" memory, marks it as "used", and returns the address of the start of the memory it just found. `free` marks some "used" memory as "free".

When you run

```
*foo = malloc(10);
```

the following happens:

- `malloc` finds 10 bytes of free memory.
- `malloc` marks those 10 bytes as used.
- `malloc` returns the address of the start of the 10 bytes it just found.
- *Your program* looks at the value of `foo`, which is an address because `foo` is a pointer.
- *Your program* stores the address `malloc` returned, at the address that was stored in `foo`.

`malloc` couldn't care less what your program does with the address it returned. It doesn't care whether your program stores it in a simple variable, an array, another `malloc`ed space, or even writes it to a file. It doesn't even care if your program forgets the address, but you should care, because your program will never be able to call `free` if it doesn't know the address of the memory it's trying to free.

Given this knowledge, you should be able to see what this code does:

```
char *bar;
bar = malloc(10);
bar = malloc(10);
free(bar);
```

Take your time to figure it out, then read below:

- A variable called `bar` is declared. Its type is `char*`.
- The program calls `malloc`.
- `malloc` finds 10 free bytes and marks them as used.
- `malloc` returns the address of the start of the 10 bytes.
- The program stores the address in `bar`. (`bar` now contains the address of the first 10 bytes)
- The program calls `malloc`.
- `malloc` finds 10 more free bytes and marks them as used.
- `malloc` returns the address of the start of the 10 bytes.
- The program stores the address in `bar`. (`bar` now contains the address of the second 10 bytes)
- The program calls `free` and passes it the address of the start of the second 10 bytes.
- `free` marks the second 10 bytes as free.

This is a memory leak. The first 10 bytes will never be freed. I can tell they'll never be freed, because the program doesn't know what address they're at.

But what about this program?

```
char *bar;
char *baz;
bar = malloc(10);

baz = bar;
baz = malloc(10);
```

Here I've called `malloc` "on" a variable that was already holding the address of something `malloc`ed. So is this a memory leak? Not by itself. The program might still `free` the first memory block, whose address is still stored in `baz`.

But, this is definitely a memory leak:

```
void func()
{
    char *bar;
    char *baz;
    bar = malloc(10);

    baz = bar;
    baz = malloc(10);
}
```

I haven't even changed the code, but just by putting it in a function, it's now a memory leak! Whaaaaaaaaa?

Remember what a memory leak actually is. A memory leak is when a program allocates memory but never frees it. You can't tell whether a program frees all its memory just by looking at the `malloc` calls.

---

As for the second part - "should I do this?"

**No**, you should not.

It will only work if the old value at the address passed to your function is a `malloc`ed pointer, *and* if the caller forgot to `free` it.

Your suggestion will break any of these functions:

```
void func1()
{
    char c;
    char *ptr = &c;
    memtest(&ptr); // Tries to free something that wasn't malloced!
    // ... do something with ptr ...
}
void func2()
{
    char *ptr;
    memtest(&ptr); // Passes a garbage address to free!
    // ... do something with ptr ...
}
void func3()
{
    char *ptr1 = malloc(5)
    char *ptr2 = ptr1;
    memtest(&ptr1);
    // ... do something with ptr1 and ptr2 ...
    free(ptr1); // Frees memory that was already freed!
}
```

In conclusion: The question in the title does not make sense. And detecting memory leaks is not as simple as this. And what you are trying to do is a bad idea.

Comment: I feel like I got the accepted answer automatically just from bothering to write a long answer. Was it actually helpful?

Comment: I am thinking the same. You got the reward for your hard work :)

Comment: Yes,more write faster is the answer accepted... ahah ;) BTW good answer.

Answer (score 5):

If the pointer for `*foo` contained the only pointer to the previously allocated memory, you've just leaked the memory that was there before.  Otherwise, it is completely innocuous.

Answer (score 5):

The call to `malloc` is irrelevant.

The problem is the assignment, if there is a problem. After you do `x=42;` the previous value of `x` is gone, no matter how important it might have been. Similarly, if `foo` is the only  pointer you have to some memory, if you overwrite `foo`, you no longer have access to that memory.

You can't call `free` without specifying what to free. So if you didn't free the memory before you lost the only pointer you had to it, you're not going to ever be able to free it, which is the definition of a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

**It causes memory leak** due to the fact that the previous allocated memory is not referred by any variable and you lost its address.

There are no specific check on that. You could set the pointer to `NULL` on declaration and set it to `NULL` each time the memory is `free`ed. Then you can check `if (pointer == NULL)` before to call `malloc`.

Using `realloc` you could avoid problems of memory leak, because if pointer is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function for the speciﬁed size. But it could causes problem if your pointer is not declared set to `NULL`.

i.e.:

```
int *foo = NULL;

void bar( void )
{
     foo = realloc(foo, 10*sizeof(int));
}
```

A good or bad feature of realloc is it preserve the content of your memory.

> Should I always do the following?

```
void memtest(char **foo)
{
        if ( *foo )
                free(*foo);

        *foo = malloc(10);
}
```

No you shouldn't because of `free` doesn't set the pointer to `NULL` and if your pointer still have the value of an already `free`ed memory the program break with error. 
I mean that such a code is error prone in case of you `free` the pointer somewhere in code without reallocating it.
And you must ensure that pointer is declared with `NULL` as init value.

Comment: It is, my personal opinion, to have a more readable code. I mean use `realloc` only when you are reallocating something previously `malloc`ated and where you want to preserve the content of memory. But you can use `realloc` only in a whole code and a single free.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when you call `malloc` on an existing variable?

There are few possibilities:

- If memory is allocated successfully by previous `malloc` then re allocating memory will cause memory leak .
- If anyhow memory allocation by previous `malloc` call is failed then there will be no memory leak.

> Should I always do the following?
>
> ```
> void memtest(char **foo)
> {
>         if ( *foo )
>                 free(*foo); 
>         *foo = malloc(10);
> }
> ```

Yes. By this way you are ensuring no memory leak.

Comment: `free` doesn't set pointer to `NULL` then `if ( *foo ) free(*foo);` is wrong. I'm missing something?

Comment: @LPs; `if ( *foo )` is checking whether previous call of `malloc` was successful. In case it was unsuccessfull, `malloc` must have returned `NULL`. So, if `*foo` is not pointing to `NULL` then free the allocating chunk.  Note that`*foo` is freed after checking `*foo` for `NULL`.

Comment: I meant that if in other part of code the memory is free and not allocated a function like that fails.

Comment: @LPs; I think I misunderstood you comment. See, `*foo = malloc(10)` will either allocate memory requested and make `*foo` to point to the first block of allocated chunk or it will return `NULL` which will be assigned to `*foo`. If allocated memory is already freed then better to assign `NULL` to the pointer pointing to that memory.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I meant. Well, is a matter of best practice for code maintenance. In case of a coder free memory without re-allocate it because it doesn't need to reallocate it. :)